# Resume downloads in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, download

I'm implementing resume download capability in ASP.NET by following the MSDN [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Implement-resume-in-aspnet-889a51ee#content)

However, I've made a few changes:

- In the aforementioned example, Download button on the HTML page makes a GET request. My Download button on ASPX page makes a POST request.
- And instead of the handler page DownloadHttpHandler.ashx.vb, I have Download.aspx.vb and this calls the appropriate function in DownloadFile.vb.

The problem is downloads do not resume in Internet Explorer 10. Upon closely inspecting the requests, I found that the Download button on my ASPX page makes a POST request. However as mentioned before, the Download button on the HTML page makes a GET request.

To further confirm if GET/POST makes any difference, I changed the GET to POST (in the original MSDN example). This was the only change I made. And as expected, downloads do not resume in Internet Explorer.

While searching for similar issues, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7967550/3961464) example. And even here only GET/HEAD requests are allowed and all other types (like POST) are explicitly not allowed.

So, if I'm not wrong, only GET requests are supported. Why?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've further explained my question.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you referenced, it is the logic required by the original post to use only GET or HEAD requests. In general, you can use

```
request.HttpMethod
```

to check for POST, GET, DELETE, PUT etc requests.

For understanding more about headers, I suggest [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

I also suggest to go over [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httpmethod.aspx) to understand HttpMethod in general.

Comment: Are you suggesting that we can have POST requests too? I still don't understand why only GET and HEAD are allowed and all other types are explicitly forbidden.

Comment: Yes you can. Only GET and HEAD are allowed **in that particular question**. Let's say you are the server and you only process GET requests. I am sending a POST request to you, how would you differentiate it? That is the reason they are checking only GET and HEAD because their server side code is only configured for those kind of requests.

Comment: Let me know if you have any other questions in mind, or if this answered your question, accepting it as the answer would go a long way.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I'm trying out <a href="http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Implement-resume-in-aspnet-889a51ee#content">this</a> 

But instead of an HTML page with a Download button, I have an aspx page and instead of (handler) ashx.vb page, I have aspx.vb. So my button on the aspx page makes a POST request instead of a GET request in case of an HTML page. And although everything else is the same, downloads do not resume in IE. To verify, I changed the GET to POST in HTML page and sure enough, IE doesn't resume downloads.
I actually wanted to confirm if this(GET/POST) makes a difference.