# Streaming audio from ASP.NET breaks in chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, streaming

I have an action that retrieves an audio file and streams it to a page for playback. Here is how we're sending the audio binary:

```
//content length and type header is required to work in chrome
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", audio.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
Response.OutputStream.Write(audio, 0, audio.Length);
Response.End();
Response.Close();
```

In Edge and IE, this works great. The file is completely sent between the time the page loads and the user presses play. However, in Chrome it only retrieves the first chunk, then waits for the user to get a ways into the playback before getting the rest. The problem is, by the time this happens the response has closed and it ends up running the entire action again.

The web server ends up trying to get the entire audio file from the data source again, which technically works on a fast enough network. However, if the connection between the web server and the data source is too slow the client ends up getting a 504 and playback stops entirely.

Ideally, I want to be able to just tell chrome to behave like the others. But I'm not sure how I would go about it. The other option I'm considering is caching the audio files on the web server, but that seems like it's not actually solving the source of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how resume able file download in asp.net with c# -> best way (for large files too)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948316/how-resume-able-file-download-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp-best-way-for-large-fil)

Comment: you are sending whole content to the browser.. you have to send data in chunks according to headers